# Copy value to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

why twb cells(i,7) value don't show up in the extwb(pasterowIndex, 1)?

can you make this

```
twb.Sheets(1).Activate
Cells(i, 7).Select
Selection.Copy
extwb.Sheets(8).Activate
Cells(pasterowIndex, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

code little simple, because I have many value to copy?

```
Sub historical()
    Dim twb As Workbook
    Dim extwb As Workbook
    Dim extwb3 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim pasterowIndex As Long
    pasterowIndex = 2

    Set twb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\faisal.abraham\Documents\Travel\PUPD.xlsx")
    Set extwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\faisal.abraham\Documents\Travel\PIRD.xlsx")

    With twb.Sheets("Actuary_Travel_Voucher_Engineer")
        For i = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If twb.Cells(i, 23).Value = "PERMATA HIJAU  " And Cells(i, 28).Value = "PAID" Then
            twb.Sheets(1).Activate
            Cells(i, 7).Select
            Selection.Copy
            extwb.Sheets(8).Activate
            Cells(pasterowIndex, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            pasterowIndex = pasterowIndex + 1
            End If
        Next i

        pasterowIndex = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My recommendation: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I can see that you are missing a `End If`. I think it should after the line `pasterowIndex = pasterowIndex + 1`

Comment: @Wizhi sorry i am forgot to input in this question, but in my original code it's already here

Comment: I'm surprised `twb.Cells(i, 23).Value` works as `twb` is a workbook not a worksheet.

Comment: @SJR I'm pretty sure too, that `twb.Cells(i, 23).Value` will throw a *Run time error “483” “Object doesn't support this property or method”*

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - aye, OP has some explaining to do. Also don't understand why `pasterowIndex` is reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
    twb.Sheets(1).Activate
Cells(i, 7).Select
Selection.Copy
extwb.Sheets(8).Activate
Cells(pasterowIndex, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

can be replaced with

```
 twb.Sheets(1).cells(i,7).copy extwb.sheets(8).cells(pasteindex,1)
```

Which doesn't fix the other issues but at least makes the code less painful